# H/W requirements for Python

Tags: python, microcontroller, ram

I have written a python program (total size 2.8 mb) that uses **SQLite**  database, need a *Microcontroller* that can run this program and how much RAM will simple Python program need ?

Comment: What is the python program? What are you trying to do? We are severely lacking in the details needed to give you a proper answer.

Comment: How can we possibly know how much RAM is sufficient without knowing what your program does or what it keeps in memory?

Comment: Python would be the last thing I'd use for a microcontroller (as in: 8/16 bit, few KB to few MBs of RAM, no operating system). As a rule of thumb, to run satisfactorily CPython you need something that is thought to run Linux (think 32 bit ARMs with tens/hundreds MBs of RAM).

Comment: (of course there's the pyboard and its ecosystem, but then you are on an alternative python implementation without an underlying OS, so you are throwing away a significant part of the "batteries included" of Python, which is one of its main attractives; besides, it has a cost comparable to a raspberry or a beaglebone that can run a full "regular" python stack without problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is interpreted language, so it requires a Python interpreter to run on anything. In order to run Python on a microcontroller you will need that microcontroller to run an OS, for which a Python interpreter is available - see [Python implementations](https://www.python.org/download/other/). You could also compile, and adapt if required, the [Python source](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/) for a particular platform you wish to use. I guess it is possible to write a loader, that will start the core Python interpreter to run your script without the OS, but it will be really challenging. So probably the microcontroller will run an OS anyway and the requirements for hardware will be dictated by the OS. Also, you could benchmark your program and make assumptions for hardware requirements based on the results.